# Dr. office moved my payments around and now double billing me?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, legal, healthcare, billing

I had to pre-pay for treatment until insurance kicked in; insurance totally messed up all the claims and paid where they should not have which made doctors billing dept. move my payment to other treatment bills.

Now insurance gets their money back, and I am being double billed for a balance on treatment I already paid 100% of. After almost a year of "holding my credit due to insurance not paying" I am now also told I owe more due to insurance not processing claims almost 10 months old.

What are my options?

Comment: Sounds like a better question for the Law stack than the Personal Finance stack

Comment: With the American health care system, I found that attempts to understand what and why are pointless. Either vote for representative who'd make universal healthcare happen or pay whatever they tell you to pay. There's no middle ground, you're either the consumer or the product, you can't be both

Comment: "I had to pre-pay for treatment until insurance kicked in" does this mean that the procedure was done before you had coverage?

Comment: treatments were pre-authorized, but insurance wouldn't pay until deductible met, so I paid until deductible met- but they moved my payments around and are now rebilling me for what I already paid for.

Comment: You should have billing/payment statements from the doctor's office and insurance company and bank documenting al the transactions. Those should be able to show exactly how much money the doctors got from who, when. If those don't match what you are being billed for now, present the details to the doctor's office and ask them to help you figure out if the mistake is theirs or yours.